# Swipe and OnClick events in RecyclerView

Tags: android, swipe, ontouchlistener, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a swipe to dismiss action in a RecyclerView but when I set an OnClickListener on any View in a ViewHolder it overrides all OnTouch events on that view.

I can abandon OnClickListener and handle all clicks in the TouchListener but if I have multiple buttons in a child view of the RecycleView than that will be a lot of code and this doesn't look like a right way.

In my RecyleView I'm setting Swipe to dismiss listeners ([similar to this](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss)):

```
    setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
```

It works in the ListView, but in the RecycleView the OnClickListener blocks OnTouchListner events.

Example of the layout for ViewHolder view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/keep_icon"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_received" />
```

Inflating in the RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.push_card_view_compat, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v, onClickListener, onKeepListener);
}
```

The ViewHolder:

```
public ViewHolder(final View itemView,
                  final OnViewHolderClickListener onClickListener,
                  final OnKeepListener onKeepListener) {
    super(itemView);
    keepButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.keep_icon);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onItemClickListener.onClick(getPosition(), itemView);
    }
    });
    keepButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onKeepListener.onClick(getPosition(), itemView);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: try adding to your xml outter ViewGroup for row items: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: @inner_class7 It didn't work.

Comment: did you add this to your parent element of your view holder?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried "afterDescendants" but neither worked.

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: Added xml and more code.

Comment: @IvanFork have you used RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener ?

Comment: @pskink Looks like a RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener is the way to go, an OnClickListener don't block its events. But it works differently than OnTouchListener and needs a little bit different implementation for swipes.

Comment: @IvanFork it works like ViewGroup's touch events: you have onInterceptTouchEvent and OnTouchEvent

Comment: Did you found the solition? If yes please share it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I achieved that by assigning `OnClickListener` for the buttons in the `ViewHolder`, and creating an interface for the touch events.

The sample project is on GitHub: https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView.

In my case each item is a `CardView` with two buttons, and I want to detect the touch events in the `CardView` and the `Button`s. The `CardView` layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/card_view_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/card_view_button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/card_view_button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then in the `Activity`, I declared an interface to receive the touch events:

```
public interface OnItemTouchListener {
    public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position);
    public void onButton1Click(View view, int position);
    public void onButton2Click(View view, int position);
}
```

And in the `ViewHolder` I assign `OnClickListeners` to the objects that I want to listen to, and call my custom listener:

```
public class CardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> cards;
    private OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener;

    public CardViewAdapter(List<String> cards, OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener) {
        this.cards = cards;
        this.onItemTouchListener = onItemTouchListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(cards.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cards == null ? 0 : cards.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private Button button1;
        private Button button2;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_title);
            button1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_button1);
            button2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_button2);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemTouchListener.onButton1Click(v, getPosition());
                }
            });

            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemTouchListener.onButton2Click(v, getPosition());
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemTouchListener.onCardViewTap(v, getPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, instantiate the custom `OnItemTouchListener` and pass it to the `CardViewAdapter` constructor:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mItems = new ArrayList<>(30);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        mItems.add(String.format("Card number %2d", i));
    }

    OnItemTouchListener itemTouchListener = new OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tapped " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onButton1Click(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button1 in " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onButton2Click(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button2 in " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    mAdapter = new CardViewAdapter(mItems, itemTouchListener);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // ... Assign the swipe listener
}
```

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this a million times! My scrolling is still a bit staggered, because of loading images... any advice on that would be great. :\

Comment: The solution is to load the image to the memory asynchronously in an AsyncTask, and then show it in the ImageView. Check this article http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#AsyncTask.
This post also talks about async loading. In the example the images are downloaded from the internet, but it is even simpler if you are loading them locally: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html